# Semidirect products of $S_n$

Tags: group-theory

**Show that $S_n$ is isomorphic to a semidirect product $C_2\ltimes A_n$ ($n\geq2$).**$$\text{---------------------------}$$
    The solution boils down to showing that $S_n=A_nC_2$, $A_n\unlhd S_n$ and that $C_2\cap A_n=e$.  I show this below.   Assuming we can do that, then by definition, we have $S_n\cong C_2\ltimes A_n$.$$$$
    By the index 2 theorem $A_n\unlhd S_n\implies C_2A_n\le S_n$.  By the fact that all of $A_n$ consists of even functions and the identity and the fact that $\# C_2=2$ therefore can contain at most a transposition which is odd we get $C_2\cap A_n=1$.  Finally $C_2\cap A_n=1$ gives $\#C_2A_n=2n!/2=\#S_n\implies S_n=C_2A_n$.  $$$$Does this seem correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Last sentence $\#C_2A_n=2n=\#G$ is not clear to me. Also, what is $G$ exactly: $S_n$ or the group generated by $C_2$ and $A_n$?

Comment: He means the orders are equal

Comment: @Alan I'm saying why $2n$?

Comment: You're correct.  It should be n!/2*2  I'll modify.  I also got rid of any references to $G$ and replaced with $S_n$